# did/have done my graduation

Tags: grammar

I wonder what is the best way to introduce in writing about my education e.g.

> " I did my graduation in economics in 2010 from Kingston University".

or

> " I have done my graduation in economics in 2010 from Kingston
>   University".

or

> " I did my graduation in economics (2010) from Kingston University".

To me there looks to be something wrong with first two sentence constructions as there is "in" twice in the sentence. But I don't know the rule which stops me writing like this.

Kindly advice.

Thanks
Ahmad

Comment: You can always write: _I graduated from Kingston University in 2010 in economics._

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using "in" twice in a sentence.  The sentence does have other problems. We do not "do" a graduation.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I wouldn't say any of those.

> I graduated from Kingston University in 2010 with a degree in economics

or

> In 2010 I received a degree in economics from Kingston University

or

> I received a degree in economics from Kingston University in 2010

Back to your sentences though. 
Using in twice in a sentence isn't necessarily a bad thing. Personally, I would stay away from parentheses. So I would refrain from using the last of your example constructions.

In your second example construction "have done" just doesn't sound normal to a native English speaker.

Your first example is correct, however, it's just better to shorten "did my graduation" to "graduated" and move "in 2010 to the end" so that it says:

> I graduated in economics from Kingston University in 2010

My personal preference is still the first one that I listed (I graduated form Kingston University in 2010 with a degree in economics)